# How the get the sizes of the dimensions of a multi-dimensional array in Chapel?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, size, chapel

Consider that we have defined the array below in Chapel:

```
var arr : [1..10] [1..5] int;
```

How to get the size of the dimensions of this array? In other words, I need a procedure that gets `arr` as the input and gives (10,5) as the output.

To get its second dimension, I used `arr.domain.dim(1).size`, but it gave me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential misunderstanding here is that your array:

```
var arr : [1..10] [1..5] int;
```

is technically not a multidimensional array in Chapel; rather it is a 1D array whose elements are each 1D arrays.  So to get the size of one of its inner arrays, you would need to take the size of an element as follows ([ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sOSOxIDVnwYKlpSVpuhY3PcsSixQSi4oUrBSiDfX0DA1iwbRprEJmXok1V3lRZklqTp4GUIVecWZVqiaqUFpmUXEJVAJiINRcmPkA)):

```
writeln(arr.size);        // the size of arr
writeln(arr.first.size);  // the size of arr[1] (and because of your declaration, arr[i]
```

This solution assumes that the arrays are 1D since we're using `size`, which will return the total number of elements in an array.

A multidimensional array in Chapel looks like this:

```
var arr: [1..10, 1..5] int;
```

and you could determine its dimensions' sizes using one of these queries ([ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sOSOxIDVnwYKlpSVpuhY3Y8sSixQSi4qsFKIN9fQMDXQUgJRprEJmXok1F1d5UWZJak6eBlCBXjFIo6Y1XAwsmJKZq2GgqVecWZWqowATMIQIaGpaQyyB2gWzEwA)):

```
writeln(arr.shape);                           // the shape of arr as a tuple
writeln((arr.dim(0).size, arr.dim(1).size));  // a tuple whose values are the sizes of each array dimension
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [array.shape](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/language/spec/arrays.html#ChapelArray.shape) will give you what you want

Comment: It gives me only the first dimension. Do you know how to use it to get the length of all dimensions? For example, in the instance I provided, it results in (10, ).

Comment: What version of Chapel are you using?  That worked for me locally, but I'm working from the latest change on Github

Comment: I am using the online version on [link](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sOSOxIDVnwYKlpSVpuhY7y4syS1Jz8jSUPFJzcvJ1FMrzi3JSFJU0rSHyUGUw5QA ). As I know, it is the updated version. Can you write the exact code you have written? @Lydia

Comment: I copied the code before you edited it, so it worked as written.  Your edit made it an array of arrays, so now it behaves as you describe